# Getting image orientation picking multiple images from gallery

Tags: android

I'm facing a problem that I cannot solve. I would be grateful if you could help me.

I would like to make an app that picks one or more images from the gallery, elaborates them and saves them into a folder.

The problem I have is to rotate the images correctly.

When I pick one image (see the code below), the app rotates the image correctly.

If I pick more images simultaneously (see the code below) I cannot rotate them because the value of "rotation" (see the code below) is always 0 (zero).

To pick one image from the gallery, I use the following code:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
```

In "OnActivityResult" I get the URI path as following:

```
Uri imageUri = data.getData();
```

To pick more images I use the following code (that doesn’t open the gallery, just the recent images, but it’s acceptable for me):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 1);
```

In "OnActivityResult" I get the URI path as following:

```
ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
```

and in a "for":

```
ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
Uri imageUri = item.getUri();
```

To get the image orientation I use the following code:

```
String[] orientationColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};
Cursor cur = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(imageUri, orientationColumn, null, null, null);
int orientation = -1;
if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
orientation = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(orientationColumn[0]));
}
```

Note: I tried to use the “ExifInterface” class but it always returns 0 (zero) on my Samsung S7 Android 7.0.

I noticed that the method to pick one image returns a URI path like “content://media/external/images/media/imageX”, instead the method to pick more images returns a URI path like “content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/imageX”. I don’t know if it can be the problem.

Thank you everybody in advance.

Vincenzo

Comment: `picks one or more images from the gallery, elaborates them and saves them into a folder.`. What do you mean by 'elaborates them'? And why would you need to know the orientation if you just wanna copy files?

Comment: ` (that doesn’t open the gallery, just the recent images, `. ??? Of course you can pick all images. Not alone recent. `How to use my phone!`.

Comment: I print some text on the images and then I save them. That's why I need to know their orientation, otherwise I cannot print the text with the correct orientation.

Comment: From Android 7 ExifInterface can load from a stream. That should do. What did you do wrong?